# Iterate condition across columns to slice pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to eliminate the rows of a pandas dataframe that exceed the 99th percentile of each column.

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1,2,3,4,100], "Col2":[11,12,13,100, 14]})
```

I would like to iterate horizontally instead of doing this *n* times:

```py
z1 = np.nanpercentile(a=df["Col1"], q=0.99) # 99th percentile of col1
z2 = np.nanpercentile(a=df["Col2"], q=0.99) # 99th percentile of col2
df = df.loc[df["Col2"] < z1]
df = df.loc[df["Col1"] < z2]
```

I noticed that I should first define all the 99th percentiles before removing rows, as doing this will affect the 99th percentile of the remaining columns. Regardless, I tried the following:

```py
for column in df:
    z = np.nanpercentile(df[column])
    df = df.loc[df[column] < z]
```

How do you iterate across columns (AKA: how do you iterate horizontally) in Python?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think your example for loop should work if you just add .keys() to the end of df. `for column in df.keys():`

Comment: try `for column in df.columns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) for this, plus checking if [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values are in the 99th percentile. This way you remove the rows which have one or more values above the 99th percentile:

```
m = df.le(df.quantile(q=0.99)).all(1)
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
   Col1  Col2
0     1    11
1     2    12
2     3    13
```

---

**Details**

```
df.le(df.quantile(q=0.99))
```

returns a boolean array:

```
    Col1   Col2
0   True   True
1   True   True
2   True   True
3   True  False
4  False   True
```

Comment: Does this approach compare each column to its corresponding 99th percentile?

Comment: Yes, try running: `df.quantile(q=0.99, axis=1)` where you can see it gets the quantile row wise. Right now it calculates the quantile per column @ArturoSbr

Comment: Awesome! One last question: what does the `le` method do? I had never seen it before.

Comment: It is the same as `<=` and stands for "less than or equal". Plus it has more flexibility with the `fill_value`argument. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) @ArturoSbr